# how to implement multiple user cms?

Tags: php, symfony, content-management-system

I would like to implement a multiple user CMS website, where each user is able to execute CRUD actions on their own records. This means that security should be implemented on record-level, not on model-level.

I've come up with 2 solutions:

1. Have an `owner_id` field in each model.
2. Have a database per user for the models that they modify. Keep a main database for all the related records (such as users' data (name, email, username, password), models that are edited by admins, but not users, etc).

---

Solution 2, I was thinking of implementing with Apache's help. I would have http://user3_website.mydomain.com/ for user3, for example, where this would be a separate website to the main website at www.mydomain.com . I would symlink all the directories apart from `/web/uploads` and `/config`:

- `/config` - I would need for the database configuration for user3
- `/web/uploads` - I would use for their uploads.

---

Is there a best practice/design pattern to implement this with Symfony? I have never developed a website that can dynamically select a database based on the user (solution 2), so am wondering if this makes sense.

I have experience with Symfony 1.x , but haven't done any development on Symfony2 yet.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with solution 1, have one database for all instances with an owner_id field. It's easier to maintain that way. At some point you may have to make changes to the database and having to do that on multiple databases can become a nightmare unless you automate that somehow.

There's hardly any advantage in doing it in separate databases unless you have some serious security issues to consider.

Comment: What if I am using a lot of 3rd party software / plugins designed for a single user? In this case I would have to extend all of those and add owner_id and be sure I don't break them.

This is the reason why I consider Solution 2.

What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your comment until now. In that case you probably don't really have a choice but to go with solution 2, extending or changing 3rd party software and plugins is likely to become a huge maintenance issue quite quickly.